# Store client data in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

We developed a E-Commerce website. Customer will come and purchase products in our site, we get payment by paypal-pro payment gateway.

Our need is, any possible to store credit-card data in payal for the particular account/user. If saved that user give all the details in the site at first time instead of giving every time of purchase.

Kindly let me know if it is available in payal or any other payment gateway.

**In other words:**
In paypal pro, user gives their card details, at that time we need to save those details. Next time if that user comes and purchase a product, we will get the amount from the card that was we already saved.It is not good to save those details in our server. So I need to save those details in paypal or any other payment systems.

Comment: Whatever information the user gives to PayPal is between the user and PayPal. Whatever information the user gives _you_ - you can save. So I can't actually understand your question. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tom: In paypal pro, user gives their card details, at that time we need  to save those details. Next time if that user comes and purchase a product, we will get the amount from the card that was we already saved.It is not good to save those details in our server. So I need to save in paypal or any other payment systems.

Comment: If your customers are saving that information on your website, then **you** are responsible for storing--and protecting--that data.  If your customers are storing that data on Paypal, then Paypal--not you--is responsible for storing the data.  Part of the reason why some people like payment systems such as Paypal is because it helps to **reduce** the number of websites with sensitive credit card information.  Why would you want to reverse that trend?  Please, **think carefully** about what you're doing and why you're doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client is based in the US then they can get a true merchant account and use a payment gateway like [Authorize.Net](http://www.authorize.net). Authorize.Net offer the [Customer Information Manager (CIM) API](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/cim/) which allows for the storage of credit card details on their server thus reducing PCI compliance and security issues.